# Many features in one model or in several models to ensemble?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science

If I have 1000 features (or more) with pairwise corrleation below 0.7, and I plan to build neural networks for predictions. Should I build one model to incorporate all features or two models with 500 features in each and then ensemble? That is:

Option 1: Model with all features. The model structure may be changed in the future if I have more features generated. For example, 100 features require 3 hidden layers and 1000 features require 6 hidden layers

Option 2: Model with fix number of features (e.g. 500). For every 500 new features that I get in the future, I just feed the data into the model without modifyting the model structure

From my perspective, if I choose the option 2, I can build a model with proper capacity to handle 500 features, and thus whenever I generate new features, I can just feed features to the existing model structure with the same network structure and even hyperparamters for ensembling. However, I have not heard of such measures in practice. I am not sure if my idea is valid or not, and I am confused which option could be better

Answer (score 1):

From my past experience and also a lot of high ranking solution on kaggle, you usually get the best by training multiple models with all features.

---

But if we have to choose between the two options, option 1 is better.

Models learn better if more features is provided.

What if feature a and b is the most useful to the final answer, but feature a is used to train model 1 and feature b is used to train model2?

Comment: Thanks. Your final statement makes sense, but I am not sure if ensemble can also solve this problem... Also, I am worrited about that the model can be too complex with too many features. What is your opinion towards this problem?  I think my situation is different from most Kagglers since I have much more time than the competition requires.

Comment: 1e9~1e10, but typically I only use 1e7~1e8 for saving time

Comment: The model is never too complex as long as you have enough data. I think it is enough to train a very complex model.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and check the results

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, go for option 2. Option 1 may sometimes overfit the model. It is true that the models learn better with more features but it may also make the model more complex. Models developed using second model is more accurate too (Even though it is based on the features selected).

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused why more features can overfit the model. Could you provide with more explanations

Comment: More the features, more the degree of polynomial in the cost function. So, there are certain possibilities that the degree chosen would overfit the given data